# How do I upgrade to Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS

Tags: server, upgrade

I want upgrade from Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS. Is there a basic update? How do I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you've been installing updates via the Update Manager or apt then you're probably already running 10.04.1. You can confirm your version by executing `lsb_release -a` on the command line.

The official documentation for upgrading can be [found here](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/upgrade).

Comment: +1 Very useful. I never knew about the lsb_relase command.

Answer (score 5):

The release of Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS is basically only an updated installation CD. If you have a completely updated installation of Ubuntu 10.4 LTS, you are effectively running Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS.

Unlike other release updates, maintenance updates don't display a special prompt in the Update Manager so it's easy to not even notice when they're installed.